# Changing List layout on the boards

Tags: trello

Any way of making it where I can have lists line up under each other instead of extending left to right on my screen.

I would much rather scroll down then sideways. Scrolling sideways requires me to either hold the control key and scroll my mouse or to actually move the mouse and move it left to right. Very counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the solution you're looking for, but you can make your browser window smaller and Trello will change into a small screen layout that has the lists positioned one on top of the other.

Comment: it no longer works